# Set a document version on Sharepoint

Tags: version-control, sharepoint-2007, document-management

Currently we are transferring our documents from a simple shared folder to an enterprise scale document management system (a.k.a. Sharepoint :) )

These documents have been living in that shared folder for some time and they all have their versions written on them. Sharepoint believes they are all version 1.

Is it possible to explicitly and forcibly set document versions for these documents on Sharepoint 2007.

Thanks...